# AppServiceConnection re-constructing already running app

Tags: uwp

We have a UWP app with a full-trust component in which the communication is handled through an `AppServiceConnection` (like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/convert-app-service-in-process)). In handling the case where the full-trust component goes down (for whatever reason, as described [here](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/)), I occasionally see the already-running UWP app get reconstructed, instead of just background activated.

The docs aren't incredibly descriptive, but it seems like `OnBackgroundActivated` on the UWP side should be called on the running instance. This is what has been happening until recently.

I haven't been able to pin down anything surrounding the cases where the UWP app gets reconstructed vs just background activated, but it causes problems because whatever state the running instance had in the `App` class is gone after getting reconstructed.

Comment: Hi, `AppServiceConnection` is used to communicate between two applications and deliver messages. If you are trying to refactor a running app, this can cause a service outage. Can you explain why?

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT - I'm not sure what you mean by "refactor a running app". We're simply using a UWP app with an in-process app service (full trust component), as described in the two links in the question. The problem is that sometimes `OpenAsync()` seems to construct a new UWP app instance instead of just calling `OnBackgroundActivated()` on the existing one.

Comment: Hi, Can you provide the minimum runnable code, we need to reproduce your problem, which will better to help you.